# How to filter content by category in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an accordion with categories. I am pulling the content from a share point list with an ajax call. Each item on the share point list has its category assigned (automotive, entertainment, housing, etc). I need every item to be filtered by category.

https://jsfiddle.net/angelogianopulos/7L392emj/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*r container = document.createElement("div");
  container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
  container.classList.add('container', 'text-center', 'my-5');*/

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://bc-net/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('specialDiscounts')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var items = data.d.results;
      console.log(items);

      var createRows = function(i, items) {

        //Creates 3 Rows inside container
        var row = document.createElement("div");

        row.setAttribute('id', 'row' + i);
        row.classList.add('row', 'animated', 'fadeInUp');

        //Appends Row to Container
        var getContainer = document.getElementById('automotive');
        getContainer.appendChild(row);

        createColumns(i, items);

      }; //End of creare Rows Function

      //Creates columns
      var createColumns = function(i, items) {

        for (var j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {

          //Creates 3 Columns inside the 3 rows
          var columns = document.createElement("div");
          columns.setAttribute('id', 'columns' + j);
          columns.classList.add('col-md-4');

          //appends the 3 columns inside the rows
          var getRow = document.getElementById('row' + i);
          getRow.appendChild(columns);

          //Create single News
          var singleNews = document.createElement("div");
          singleNews.setAttribute('id', 'singleNews' + j);
          singleNews.classList.add("single-news", "mb-4");

          var getColumns = document.getElementById('columns' + j);
          getColumns.appendChild(singleNews);

          //Inside Row
          var insideRow = document.createElement("div");
          insideRow.setAttribute('id', 'insideRow' + j);
          insideRow.classList.add('row');

          var getsingleNews = document.getElementById('singleNews' + j);
          getsingleNews.appendChild(insideRow);

          //Col-md-3
          var insideCol = document.createElement("div");
          insideCol.setAttribute('id', 'insideCol' + j);
          insideCol.classList.add('col-md-3');

          //Col-md-9
          var insideColRight = document.createElement("div");
          insideColRight.setAttribute('id', 'insideColRight' + j);
          insideColRight.classList.add('col-md-9');

          var getInsideRow = document.getElementById('insideRow' + j);
          getInsideRow.appendChild(insideCol);
          getInsideRow.appendChild(insideColRight);

          //Rounded Image Class
          var rounded = document.createElement("div");
          rounded.setAttribute('id', 'rounded' + j);
          rounded.classList.add('rounded', 'z-depth-1', 'mb-4');

          var getinsideCol = document.getElementById('insideCol' + j);
          getinsideCol.appendChild(rounded);

          //Pulls the images from the list
          var image = document.createElement("img");
          image.setAttribute('id', 'image' + j);
          image.classList.add("img-fluid");
          image.src = items[j].Image.Url;

          var getRounded = document.getElementById('rounded' + j);
          getRounded.appendChild(image);

          //Pulls header from the list
          var title = document.createElement("p");
          title.setAttribute('id', 'title' + j);
          title.innerHTML = items[j].Title;
          title.classList.add("font-weight-bold", "dark-grey-text");

          insideColRight.appendChild(title);

          var justifyContent = document.createElement('div');
          justifyContent.setAttribute('id', 'justifyContent' + j);
          justifyContent.classList.add('d-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'topSpace');

          insideColRight.appendChild(justifyContent);

          var textTruncate = document.createElement('div');
          textTruncate.setAttribute('id', 'textTruncate' + j);
          textTruncate.classList.add('col-11', 'text-truncate', 'pl-0', 'mb-3');


          justifyContent.appendChild(textTruncate);

          //Pulls anchor from the list
          var anchor = document.createElement("a");
          anchor.setAttribute('id', 'anchor' + j);
          anchor.setAttribute('href', items[j].Link.Url, +j);
          anchor.setAttribute('target', '_blank', +j);
          anchor.classList.add("dark-grey-text");
          anchor.innerHTML = items[j].Description;

          textTruncate.appendChild(anchor);

          var arrowAnchor = document.createElement("a");
          arrowAnchor.setAttribute('id', 'arrowAnchor' + j);
          arrowAnchor.setAttribute('target', '_blank' + j);
          arrowAnchor.setAttribute('href', items[j].Link.Url, +j);

          justifyContent.appendChild(arrowAnchor);

          var iconArrow = document.createElement('i');
          iconArrow.classList.add('fas', 'fa-angle-double-right');

          var getarrowAnchor = document.getElementById('arrowAnchor' + j);
          getarrowAnchor.appendChild(iconArrow);

          //var test = document.getElementById( 'arrowAnchor' + j);
          //test.onclick = function() {
          //  console.log('Hello');
          //}

        } //End of j Loop
        return;


      } // End of createColumns function

      //Array of categories
      var catGroup = [];
      console.log(catGroup);


      if (items.length > 0) {


        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

          var categories = items[i].Category;
          console.log(categories)
          catGroup.push(categories);

          if (catGroup[i] === "Automotive") {
            var automotive = document.getElementById('automotive');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Entertainment") {
            var entertainment = document.getElementById('entertainment');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Health and Beauty") {
            var health = document.getElementById('health');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Travel") {
            var travel = document.getElementById('travel');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Electronics") {
            var electronics = document.getElementById('electronics');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Services") {
            var services = document.getElementById('services');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          }
          if (catGroup[i] === "Housing") {
            var housing = document.getElementById('housing');
            console.log(catGroup[i]);

          } else {}

          if (i % 3 == 0) {
            createRows(i, items);

          } //end of % if statement

        } //End of for loop



      } //End of if item.length statement

    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("Error: " + data);
    }
  }); //End Service Icons  //End Service Icons

}); //End ready function
```

I expect every item to be placed by category in its own content panel[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T10n.jpg)

Comment: What prevents you to do the thing? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your question, what I understood is you just want to filter your data on the basis of 'category assigned'.
I will refer you to use *JavaScript Filter* like so:

```
const result = items.filter(Category => Category === "Automotive" );
```

Or, if you can use *Lodash*, there are a lot of ways to filter and even you can group by the Category.
You can check out here for *Lodash*: 
[Documentation Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Hi @Pratap Chauhan,
Yes that is the first step, to filter by category and then build all the rows and columns.

Comment: @JuanAngelogianopulos, so are facing an issue with building rows and columns or to filter the data?